# R: Automatic selection of covariates in GWR

Tags: r, modelling, geographically-weighted-regression

I am performing `geographically weighted regression (GWR)` and I have 4 covariates and 1 dependent variable. I want to find the best combination of covariates that yields the lowest AIC score. But having 4 covariates means that I have to search among 24 models (4! = 4 * 3 * 2 = 24). I was wondering if there is an automatic way to do that in R, that is, to search for the best model. Here is the code using all the covariates:

```
    library(raster)
    library(spgwr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(maptools)
    library(beepr)
    
    block.data = read.csv(file = "path/block.data.csv")
    
    x = as.data.frame(block.data$x)
    y = as.data.frame(block.data$y)
    
    coordinates(block.data) = c("x", "y")
        
    eq1 <- ntl ~ pop + tirs + evi + ebbi
        
   abw <- gwr.sel(eq1, data = block.data, adapt = T, gweight = gwr.Gauss); beep(7)
    
    abw
    
    ab_gwr <- gwr(eq1, 
                  data = block.data,
                  adapt = abw, 
                  gweight = gwr.Gauss,
                  hatmatrix = T, 
                  se.fit = T); beep(7)
    
    ab_gwr
```

My data can be found [here](https://easyupload.io/gjns8x).

Comment: I make it 16 models - a null model, four with one covariate, 6 with two covariates (4*3/2), four with 3 covars (4*3*2/(3*2)) and one with four covariates.

Comment: Do you have some measure of nonstationarity in your data? If not, GWR is not an appropriate method. If you simply have global autocorrelation, use an autoregressive model. With GWR, you do not have a stable global estimate of the variance or likelihood so, AIC is questionable. However, the common convention is that AIC is quite invalid but, what else are you going to do? I do question the method for parameter mining. I would say that you should come up with hypothesis around groups of parameters and test competing models. Otherwise, if you go to publish this work, you may have serious issues.

Comment: Also, make sure that you have a null model in the mix and, if you do have a nonstationarity effect in your data, please look for alternatives to GWR. There are serious issues that have never been addressed by Frothingham. There are some good nonparametric alternatives. Since GWR does not provide a 1st order estimate of the process or actual parameter estimates, there is no inferential advantage in staying with a "linear" method. Recursive partitioning approaches are quite effective in dealing with nonstarionarity and you can even explore the specific parameter space around these observations.

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyEvans, you always provide helpful comments. I haven't checked the alternatives but I am aware of GWR's limitations. I do have an indicator of spatial non-stationarity, I haven't post it in the code above. As for the number of potential models, you are right Spacedman, I am sorry.

Comment: Well, even Marie-Josée Fortin admits "GWR is completely incorrect but, it is what we have". However, I believe that, until somebody figures out to account for 1st order global effects, it should be kept to exploratory analysis and not used in formal inference. Currently, it dramatically overfits to 2nd order local process and cannot provide valid parameter estimates. Although, I admit that I use the model occasionally and it can be a powerful tool for finding functional scales to define a supported analytical scale used in other analysis.

Comment: Well, to be honest at the moment I am using it as an explanatory tool. But my intention is to use it to downscale satellite images (either with spline interpolation or with area-to-point kriging). But that will be a future topic. Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct and manipulate formulae as character objects and convert them to formulae. Here's something:

```
covars = names(block.data)[-1]
L = unlist(sapply(1:4,
  function(n)combn(covars, n, 
      FUN=function(x){
        as.formula(
       paste("ntl ~",paste(x,collapse=" + "))
   )},simplify=FALSE)))
L
[[1]]
ntl ~ pop
<environment: 0x56154e19f260>

[[2]]
ntl ~ tirs
<environment: 0x56154e1a0ee0>
[etc]
[[15]]
ntl ~ pop + tirs + evi + ebbi
<environment: 0x56154e3ee048>
```

Each element of `L` is a formula.

```
> abw <- gwr.sel(L[[1]], data = block.data, adapt = T, gweight = gwr.Gauss);
> ab_gwr <- gwr(L[[1]],
   [etc]
```

Now write a loop or `*apply` call over all of `L`, extract the AIC, and with Jeffrey Evans' comments in your head and all the other critiques of GWR considered, write your paper...

Comment: Thank you very much @Spacedman. The only thing I changed it was the first line in your code, where I replaced `covars = names(block.data)[-1]` with `covars = names(block.data)[-c(1:3)]`. Your solution solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a riff on @Spacedman's approach that provides an all parameters combination formula object that can be passed to lapply to iterate models.

```
p <- names(block.data)[-which(names(block.data) %in% "ntl")]
 id <- unlist(lapply(1:length(p), function(x) combn(1:length(p), x, 
              simplify=FALSE)), recursive=FALSE)
   ( f <- lapply(id, function(x) as.formula(paste("ntl ~ ", paste(p[x], collapse="+")))) )
 res <- lapply(f, function(x) {
   abw <- gwr.sel(x, data = block.data, adapt = T, gweight = gwr.Gauss) 
   gwr(x, data = block.data, adapt = abw, gweight = gwr.Gauss, 
   hatmatrix = TRUE, se.fit=TRUE) } )
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeffrey. Your code worked perfectly

Comment: This doesn't do the bandwidth selection step for each model to compute `abw` for each model, using whatever value of `abw` is hanging around before running. Is it independent of covariates?